We flip the binary string 0 to 1 and 1 to 0, But in my code Time limit Exceeded Problem are come how to resolve?
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n=int(input())
    s=input()
    c=0
    for i in range(1,n):
        if s[i]==s[i-1]:
            c+=1
            t=s[i:]
            k=s[:i]
            for i in t:
                if i=='0':
                    k+='1'
                else:
                    k+='0'
            s=k
        else:
            pass
    print(c)


You are given a binary string  of length N. You can perform the
following operation on it: Choose an index  i  (1≤i≤N), and flip every
character of S from index  i to N. Flipping a character means turning
it from 0 to 1 and vice versa. For example, if  S=1001101 and you
choose i=4, the resulting string will be S=1000010. Find the minimum
number of operations required to turn S into an alternating string. S
is said to be an alternating string if  s[i] not equal to S[ i−1]  for
every i from 2 to N.

But in my code Time limit Exceeded Problem are come how to resolve?

The whole point of problems like this is for you to figure out a more efficient solution than just the naive iterative algorithm.

Are you sure your algorithm is even correct? It's not obvious that this finds the minimum number of flips. Going through the string in order may not be optimal.

Your algorithm is O(n^2). It's a problem solving exercise to find a more efficient way.

Reduce the time complexity by performing all the checks in a single pass.
From the problem description:
S is said to be an alternating string if s[i] not equal to S[i−1] for every i from 2 to N.
This means that if S[i] == S[i - 1] a flip is required.
The task is to:
Find the minimum number of operations required to turn S into an alternating string.
In the following code:

The alternate dictionary maps '1' to '0' and '0' to '1', it's used to flip characters.

prev is initialized to the first character of the string S, it represents the previous character encountered.

The algorithm iterates through the string S starting from the second character (index 1).

At each step, the current character S[i] is compared with the value of the previous character prev.

If the characters match the flip count is incremented and the value of prev is changed to the alternate value. This simulates flipping the value of S[i] before performing the next iteration.

Otherwise, prev is assigned the value of S[i].


def flips_to_alternate(S):
    # Count the number of flips needed to make S alternating
    flips = 0
    alternate = {"1": "0", "0": "1"}
    # Initialise `prev` to `S[i - 1]`
    prev = S[0]
    for i in range(1, len(S)):
        if S[i] == prev:
            prev = alternate[S[i]]
            flips += 1
        else:
            prev = S[i]

    return flips

